# Hide all LI`s except the selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I want to hide all other LI's in a certain UL except the LI that I select.

```
<ul>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><div></div></li>     -- HIDE
  <li><div></div></li>     -- SELECT
  <li><div></div></li>     -- HIDE
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

How can I solve this the best way?

I've tried using indexes, but having some problems getting it to work, and selecting the correct UL. As you may see, I've got no class on the UL's or LI's so I think the only option is LI's.

What I really do, is selecting a div inside the LI so, I get the selected LI's index by:

```
var li_index = $(this).parent().index();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You traverse the DOM up from the div that was clicked then hide the other elements with `.not($(this).parent()).toggle()` -> Not the `li` that surrounds this `div`

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not($(this).parent()).toggle();
});
```

`.toggle()` can be replaced with `.hide()` if you don't want the User to be able to reverse their decision.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDmy3/2/

Answer (score 2):

Tried something like this?

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li').not(this).hide();
```

Or

```
$('li', $(this).closest('ul')).not(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a jQuery element set with all relevant `<li>` elements, then remove the selected element. For example:

```
$('ul#mylist li').not(selector).hide();
```

From the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .not() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; the elements that don't match the selector will be included in the result.

Instead of a selector, you can also give the element object itself if you have a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$( 'ul li' ).click( function( e ) {
        // by default, hide all li's
    $( 'ul li' ).hide();
        // show only the selected li
    $( this ).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BqKun/

Hope this helps.